# Is there a way to know if there were TypeScript compile errors in Visual Studio 2013 Update 4?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I am just starting to use TypeScript, using VS2013, update 4. One of the gotchas I am running into is that when you save a TypeScript file, sometimes it creates the JavaScript file, and sometimes it doesn't. When it does not create the JavaScript file, there is no indication to me that it failed. The Output window does not contain any clue and the Intellisense highlighting doesn't show an error either. When this happens, if I go to the browser and try something, I am constantly left confused as to whether it's a logical problem/bug in my code, or a technical problem that it failed to compile. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior of TypeScript plugin is quite unorthodox. The way it communicates success/failure is by displaying a single line in VS status bar.

Error messages look like:

```
Input file(s) contained semantic errors. If declaration flag is specified, output generation of declaration files will be skipped.
```

Success message:

```
Output(s) generated successfully.
```

I agree it is quite inconvenient. I trained myself to look at the status bar every time I save changes in .ts file.

Comment: Holy cow! I've been using TypeScript for a week or so and never noticed this. Thanks! It is awkward, but if I know where to look, I can work.